# iOS: App crash when trying to save image using PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash, phphotolibrary

I'm trying to save photo using PHPhotoLibrary. That photo I saved in the app document folder as temp file.

Below is my store photo code, running background using NSOperationQueue

```
- (void)_storePhotoToAblum:(NSDictionary *)photoDic {
    NSString *fileName = (NSString *)[photoDic valueForKey:@"Path"];

    NSString *fileURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _rootPath, fileName];

    NSArray *folders = (NSArray *)[photoDic objectForKey:@"albumName"];

    // Add it to the photo library
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
         PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileURL]];

        for (NSString *folderID in folders) {
            // if have custom albums
            PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
            options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", folderID];

            PHAssetCollection *collection = [[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:options] firstObject];
            if (collection) {
                // Save photo in album
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection];

                [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];

            }
        }
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
             [self.delegate updateDuplicatePhoto:fileURL withPhotoInfo:photoDic success:YES orError:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error:%@", error.localizedDescription);
            [self.delegate updateDuplicatePhoto:fileURL withPhotoInfo:photoDic success:NO orError:error];
        }
    }];
}
```

`photoDic` is a dictionary which contains "path" as String, "size" as String and "albumName" as an array.

I've already create all the customer albums before starting the photo saving process.

And the delegate function in completion handler only for deleting the temp file in the app document folder.

But I got an crash report below:

```
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  8

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x183c642d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1959380e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183b4af70 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 412
3   CoreFoundation                  0x183b57200 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 60
4   Content Transf                  0x1001048bc __39-[PhotoStoreHelper _storePhotoToAblum:]_block_invoke + 588 (PhotoStoreHelper.m:109)
5   Photos                          0x187d36424 __51-[PHPhotoLibrary performChanges:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 48
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x195fb5994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x195fb5954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x195fc00a4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1448
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x195fb8a5c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x195fc2318 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x195fc3c4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x19619522c _pthread_wqthread + 816
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x196194ef0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001960fb270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019619916c pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000196072b14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195105414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195124b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001959383bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195121bb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000195121474 __cxa_throw + 132
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000195938200 objc_exception_throw + 344
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b4af6c -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 408
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b571fc +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 56
11  Content Transf                  0x00000001001048b8 __39-[PhotoStoreHelper _storePhotoToAblum:]_block_invoke + 584 (PhotoStoreHelper.m:109)
12  Photos                          0x0000000187d36420 __51-[PHPhotoLibrary performChanges:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 44
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fb5990 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fb5950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fc00a0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1444
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fb8a58 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fc2314 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 716
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195fc3c48 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196195228 _pthread_wqthread + 812
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000196194eec start_wqthread + 0
```

crashed on line:

```
[assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
```

It seems like the assetChangeRequest placeholder returns nil, and I'm adding this nil into an array.

I'm trying to replicate this issue, but if photoDic comes with nil, the URL I'm creating will be incorrect, and this function will return failure handler with error;

If fileURL is not correct, and I cannot find the file, this function will return failure handler with cannot finish operation error instead of crashing the app;

If something wrong with getting the folder information, the crashing line never get called, because I have for loop and an if clause to handle the empty case.

It never crash on that line.

Is there any case `placeholderForCreatedAsset` will become nil? or any other case I didn't cover may cause this issue and generate this crash report?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you know in what case creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL will return nil? so I will try to replicate it.@Cristik

Comment: @Cristik Thanks. I'll add some check for it.